# When setting some colClasses to integer, read.table complains when it sees quoted field values

Tags: r, import, data.table, read.table, read.csv

I'm learning R by using a dataset of historical loans from Lending Club. Representative subset of data here: https://gist.github.com/adetch/11b1c2b6eac0b6add23f

The command in question:

```
problem <- read.csv("test.csv",na.strings=c("","<NA>"),colClasses=c("mths_since_last_major_derog"="integer"))
```

The error I hit:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
scan() expected 'an integer', got '""'
```

I hit a similar problem with the following command:

```
problem <- read.csv("test.csv",na.strings=c("","<NA>"),colClasses=c("id"="integer"))
```

The error in this case:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
scan() expected 'an integer', got '"1077501"'
```

So it seemed/seems to me that

- `R`'s `integer` class is incompatible with quotation marks
- and possibly that the `na.strings` conversion runs after the scan of the classes, and the `integer` check fails on empty strings.

However, other columns wrapped in `""` such as `member_id` and `loan_amnt` get cast as `integer` without complaint (and also without any special intervention using `colClasses`!).

The proximate question:

- How do I cast these fields (`id`, `mths_since_last_major_derog`) as integer, rather than factor (noting there are numerous other fields that *should* be cast as factors)

More importantly:

- Where is my mental model of `R` classes, class coercion, read.table/read.csv, etc breaking down?

Comment: I've never used named vectors for colClasses before, but I do see could be very useful. There were some changes to `scan` to accommodate the long integer/numeric processing changes in R 3.0.+. Perhaps this is a side-effect?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `colClasses`. If you really need to coerce, then read it as-is and then `use$id <- as.integer(problem$id)`

but in this case (your `test.csv`) i think R is pretty good at loading the data.

**EDIT**

Just to re-iterate. Imagine having a simple data table with 3 columns:

```
id,member_id,term
1077501,1296599,36 months
1077430,1314167,60 months
1077175,1313524,36 months
1076863,1277178,36 months
```

if you load the data via

```
d <- read.csv("c:/temp/R/data.csv")
```

then R will do its best to match the data types.
If you really want to tell it upfront, using `colClasses`; if you say something like

```
d <- read.csv("c:/temp/R/data.csv", colClasses = c("integer"))
```

then it will try to use the class `integer` for every columns, since it is *repeating* the `colClasses` vector.

The same problem with

```
d <- read.csv("c:/temp/R/data.csv", colClasses = c("integer","character"))
```

Tries to load 1st column as `colClasses[1]`, i.e. integer - OK.

Tries to load 2nd column as `colClasses[2]`, i.e. character - OK.

Tries to load 3rd column as - since there is no `colClasses[3]` then it *recycles* `colClasses` and goes back to `colClasses[1]` - and this won't work (R doesnt know how to coerce '36 months' to an integer value)

**EDIT2**

AFter actually looking at the dataset, the problem is that your column does not have any values, and stores only `""`.
So you need to add `""` to your `na.string` and that will do the trick:
(i.e. you need to escape the `"`, your actual string will be `"\"\""`)

```
problem <- read.csv("c:/temp/R/test.csv",na.strings=c("\"\"","","<NA>"),colClasses=c("mths_since_last_major_derog"="integer"))
```

Comment: @BondedDust had a comment on the question, but removed it; so just to re-iterate: `colClasses` is OK to use, but if the vector is not long enough, it will be recycled.

Comment: What's the reason to shy away from `colClasses`? My understanding was that providing R with the classes ahead of time dramatically speeds up `read.table/read.csv`.

Comment: what do you mean "if the vector is not long enough, it will be recycled"?

Comment: "but in this case (your test.csv) i think R is pretty good at loading the data." Note, though, that the size of the actual `csv`'s is 300mb.

Comment: If you have 20 columns in the CSV, but your colClasses has 4, then in order to match them, the colClasses is going to be re-used; for columns 1-4, 5-8 etc. Let me modify the answer with an example - bear with me.

Comment: Doing some reading, it looks like `colClasses` *doesn't* accept a named vector! Rather, it accepts such a vector, but ignores the names?!

Comment: It does. `d <- read.csv("c:/temp/R/data.csv", colClasses = c("term"="character", "member_id" = "integer", id ="character") )` is valid.

Comment: Ok, in such a case, do the unspecified columns still fallback to default behavior? The `colClasses` docs say "unspecified values are taken to be NA."

Comment: You can use `NA` to ignore columns.  `colClasses = c("integer", "character", NA)`

Comment: "to ignore columns" meaning omit them from the `read.csv` operation entirely? In that case, it sounds like `colClasses` is all or nothing.

Comment: Ahhhh i.e. you need to escape the ", your actual string will be "\"\"" Thanks! I'll try this!